# Testing if one list is a sublist of another without testing equality between elements

Tags: algorithm, haskell, recursion, functional-programming, ocaml

I am wondering if one can write a functional program (as in Haskell or OCaml) that takes two lists and determines if the first is a sublist of the second, with the property that the program cannot invoke equality between elements of the list.

**More generally, is there such a program that works for lists of elements of arbitrary type?** That is, (in Haskell terms) the type does not have to be constrained by Eq, Ord, or something else.

The reason I ask this is that when dealing with lists of elements of arbitrary type, standard equality (as for ints, strings, etc.) is sometimes not supported for these elements. It would be helpful, however, to test for sublists.

I have been unable to think of an implementation that meets this condition. Is it possible to create one?

Comment: Okay, you don't want to use `(==)` for equality. What do you want to use instead?

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm not sure. I'm asking for a program that works for lists whose elements can't be compared by equality.

Comment: @CuriousKid7: In general, that'd be equivalent to solving the Halting problem, since arbitrary lists may contain function values, and comparing functions for equality is undecidable.

Comment: Can you write down what "sublist" *means* without using equality between elements?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Without an equality, the relation `is_sublist` is non-sensical: `` [x] `is_sublist` [y] `` ought to be true if and only if `x` = `y`. Conversely, if such function `is_sublist` existed, it would define an equality function as `` eq x y = [x] `is_sublist` [y] `` .